# python datetime printing vs appending to list shows different results

Tags: python, datetime

I'm confused on why I'm getting different results. I would like to generate a list or dates in this format 2019-01-01T00:00:00:

```
start_date ='2019-01-01T00:00:00'
end_date ='2019-01-31T23:59:59'
start_date_object = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
end_date_object = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

start_date_list=[]
print start_date_object
start_date_list.append(start_date_object)
print start_date_list
```

But here are the results:

Print statement:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00
```

Print list:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime` has methods for formatting its value in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When printing a single `datetime` object, its `str` is used. When an object is part of a list, its `repr` method is used to represent it. Compare:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date ='2019-01-01T00:00:00'
start_date_object = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

print(str(start_date_object))
# 2019-01-01 00:00:00

print(repr(start_date_object))
# datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str(datetime_object)`, and download Python3 :)

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date =' 2019-01-01T00:00:00'
end_date = '2019-01-31T23:59:59'
start_date_object = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
end_date_object = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

start_date_list = []
print start_date_object
start_date_list.append(str(start_date_object))
print start_date_list
```